# How to change color, size and shape of elements in a range slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I don't have any expertise in coding or web development. After hours of research in Google, I ended up writing a set of **(perfectly working)** codes to build a range slider with HTML, CSS and JS.

I'm using this slider to change media volume in my smartphone, in [this Media Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z98CM.jpg) created using an Android application called Tasker. My slider is functional, **but I want to make some cosmetic changes to my slider.**

**Could someone please help me to implement following into my code?**

1. Color / gradient of the slider portion before the thumb.
2. Color / gradient of  the slider portion after the thumb.
3. Size, shape, color, and opacity of the thumb.

This is the current code. Feel free to edit this.

```html
<div class = "container">
    <input type="range" 
    min="0" 
    max="25" 
    step="any" 
    value="%VOLM" 
    id="volm">
</div>

<style>
.container{
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:5
}

#volm{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: magenta;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width:153px;
    height:5px;
</style>

<script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("volm");
    slider.addEventListener("input",function() 
{
    performTask("WebView Slider - Media Volume",1,slider.value,)}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: performTask is not defined` is this also part of the problem?

Comment: Why not make a custom slider element? That way you will have better control on the UI.

Comment: @consolenine, honestly I don't know. The existing code is something that I figured out and after spending hours in Google. A mix of many tutorials.

Comment: @DavidThomas It is the output of this slider. Whenever I move the slider, the slider value is sent to that specified task, which is outside this code (Tasker Android app)... Dont mind that... All I want now is to make some cosmetic changes to my slider. Rest are working fine.

Comment: @ShebeerPrince Study this CodePen, it is really useful https://codepen.io/brandonmcconnell/pen/oJBVQW

Comment: @consolenine Thank you mate. I'll read it and try out myself asap 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML Range Input has the following two pseudo-elements:

1. -webkit-slider-runnable-track
2. -webkit-slider-thumb

You can style them using the pseudo-selectors.
This [CodePen](https://codepen.io/brandonmcconnell/pen/oJBVQW) has a clever solution in achieving what you intend. By using box-shadows on the thumb, you can style the area before and after the thumb.
Use multiple box-shadows + blurring to achieve gradient-like effects.

I edited your code a little to show how the above can be achieved. Rest is just about preferences on how you want the slider to look like. You can also use JavaScript to dynamically change property values depending on the input.

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:5;
    height: fit-content;
}

#volm{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width:153px;
    height: 5px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: hsl(0deg, 0%, 90%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
} 
input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  position: relative;
  left: initial;
  bottom: 5px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: -340px 0 0 320px #1597ff, inset 0 0 0 40px #1597ff, 340px 0 0 320px #00f18f, inset 0 0 0 40px #1597ff;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
    <input type="range" 
    min="0" 
    max="25" 
    step="any" 
    value="%VOLM" 
    id="volm">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend @consolenine. 

You gave me everything I want. I made [a few changes to your code](https://pastebin.com/nNPg6Nd6) and achieved what exactly I was looking for. Thanks a lot for helping me and teaching me at the same time.

Will do a study on how to implement gradient as you mentioned. Since it is not that important, I'm finalizing my code for now.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Hey @consolenin, [this is how](https://imgur.com/a/xHO0XXJ) my sliders looks like after implementing what you taught me. Thanks ☺️

Comment: I removed left hand side thumb shadow completely, then set slider background as a gradient using "background: linear-gradient(to right,1stColor,2ndColor);" to make a [gradient like this](https://imgur.com/a/lNhEmIP). Thank you for your code from which only I'm improving steb by step according to my taste 